# Difference between two dates based on ID and condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have to calculate the date difference between two rows for each unique ID (shipment-number) where the first time is categorized as (pickup) and the last time is categorized as (delivery). In essence, is there a way to create a calculated field or equivalent in Quicksight (or SQL) which does the following (where shipment number, event-type, and event-time are column names):

`for each unique shipment-number find the date difference (event-time) between event-type == delivered and event-type == pickup`

Assuming there are four rows for a specific shipment number:

| shipment-number | event-type | event-type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | pickup | 11.01.2021 |
| 001 | in-transit | 12.01.2021 |
| 001 | arrived-destination | 13.01.2021 |
| 001 | delivered | 15.01.2021 |

then the expected result would be the difference from 11.01.2021 (pickup) and 15.01.2021 (delivered) which is 4 days.

I have tried using datediff, however, this requires two date fields. Creating two fields (firstEvent) and (lastEvent) by extracting the time of the event by the event-type for each unique shipment-number could be a possibility? However, I am unsure as to do so.

Any help/advice would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select shipment_number,
       datediff(day, min(case when event_type = 'pickup' then event_date end) 
       - max(case when event_type = 'delivered' then event_date end)  ) as diff
  from your_table
group by shipment_number
```

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but would this allow me to visualize the result in Quickisght with the other data (does it add a row to my table)?

Comment: It is select query and it will not add anything to your table

Comment: I'll give it a go. I'm hoping I could save the query output and do a join in order to get the additional field diff in my table for analysis.

Comment: You can accept the answer if it works for you so that this question is marked as resolved